# Python function question about if-elif function

Tags: python

Below is my answer for a question on Hackerrank.

However, when I run the code, 2 values appeared in the terminal. One of which is a None value. I'm not sure which line of code created this None value. Please advice. Thank you

**Code:**

```
def is_weird(num):
    if num % 2 == 1:
        print("Weird")
    elif num % 2 == 0 and 2 <= num <= 5:
        print("Not Weird")
    elif num % 2 == 0 and 6 <= num <= 20:
        print("Weird")
    elif num % 2 == 0 and num > 20:
        print("Not Weird")

N = int(input("Enter number: "))
print(is_weird(N))
```

**Terminal output:**

> Enter number: 8
>   Weird
>   None

Comment: `print(is_weird(N))` -> `is_weird(N)`. Or don't print inside function, instead use `return`.

Comment: you are trying to print response from your function, currently you are returning nothing. So only need to call the function instead of print `is_weird(N)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python function returns `None` by default. In your case, the `is_weird()` function is returning `None`.
So, when you enter 8 as input, your function prints `"Weird"` because of the print statement inside the function and then it returns `None`. This value gets printed because of the line `print(is_weird(N))`

Your isweird() function is equivalent to:

```
def is_weird(num):
    if num % 2 == 1:
        print("Weird")
    elif num % 2 == 0 and 2 <= num <= 5:
        print("Not Weird")
    elif num % 2 == 0 and 6 <= num <= 20:
        print("Weird")
    elif num % 2 == 0 and num > 20:
        print("Not Weird")
    return None
```